# tt_news No categories when creating news

Tags: typo3, categories, typo3-6.2.x, tt-news

When I create a new article in the News administration of tt_news in Typo3 6.2, I am not able to select any categories in the "Options" window of the news, as there are none listed. But I have categories created and I can assign already existing new to categories, if I select it in the "Items" window of the category itself.

In [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxJHo.jpg) you can see there are no categories listed, when creating or editing news entries, although there are some.

When I try to assign news to a category in the list module (opening the category and assigning a news item to it via "Items" section) it works, as you can see in [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pj95q.jpg).

I have looked up if I need to specify for tt_news where the categories are stored, but I have not been able to find anything and I cannot remember doing so in the past (for other pages). Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out ...?

To me it looks like you confused the tt_news categories, they would not show in the tab in image 1 ...

You'd edit this selecting the folder where your news is stored, selecting the article you'd like to assign to a category and then the 'Categories & Relations' tab ...

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: absolutely, I do not have the ... credits, credentials or what to comment, I was looking for an answer and figured I could be helping Bernie ...